# how to wrap a C++ argument-less macro with SWIG?

Tags: swig

I read here how to wrap this macro `FOOBAR` in SWIG:

```
class foobar {
public:
    static void method() {}
};

#define FOOBAR() foobar().method()
```

The solution is to include this in SWIG interface:

```
void FOOBAR();
```

However, suppose I drop `()` so that my macro is

```
#define FOOBAR foobar().method()
```

This is still perfectly legitimate macro I can use in C++.  How do I wrap this, so I can say on Python command line:

```
>>>FOOBAR
```

To clarify, since this seems to be confusing.  I purposely chose the method to return nothing.  I did that, so that the irrelevant question of "what is it supposed to return" is not considered.  However, people still seem to want to consider it.

OK then, in C++, `FOOBAR` has meaning - it is a certain object, I can call `FOOBAR.someMethod()`.  I want that on Python command line, it also be an object (the equivalent one), which will behave the same, I also want to call `FOOBAR.someMethod()` and have it behave the same as in C++.

I am sorry, but I assumed, that in the context of SWIG, the above explanation is obvious and unnecessary, and is contained in the abbreviation "wrap".

Comment: You could never call a function with that syntax from Python.  Python requires the `()`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I did not say I wanted a Python function.  I wrote my question very carefully and spent a lot of time making it "just right".

Comment: From your post above: `...so I can say on Python command line >>> FOOBAR`.  You'd have to say `>>> FOOBAR()` to call something in Python.  That's all I was referring to.

Comment: @MarkGaleck We appreciate your attention to detail, however it is still not clear (whether a question is worded "just right" is determined from people's answers, not your opinion). So, what do you expect to see once you press enter after FOOBAR? Because in the C++ code, writing `int main() { FOOBAR; }` *is* a function call, which is why Tolonen commented as he did: in Python, a function requires '()' (in C++ too, but C++ macros can hide this, there is no such thing in Python).

Comment: @MarkTolonen No, I don't have to say `FOOBAR()`.  I can say `FOOBAR` and as long as that variable had been assigned, no error will happen.

Comment: @Schollii "what I expect to see?" follows from my question.  There is nothing in my question, if you read it carefully, about what I expect.  Therefore, it is not assumed that I expect any result in particular.  What I _do_ expect however, is also stated in my question, I expect that I "can" say `FOOBAR`.  What that means, is, I will say it, and no error will occur.  That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%pythoncode` may be what you want.  Example:

```
%module x

%inline %{
class foobar {
public:
    static void method() {}
};

#define FOOBAR foobar().method()
%}

%pythoncode %{
FOOBAR = foobar().method
%}
```

Result:

```
>>> from x import *
>>> FOOBAR
<built-in function foobar_method>
```

Comment: May very well be.  Thank you.  I will check it out as soon as I get to my machine.